# wxpython skips over a call to my function, and jumps directly to the next line. Why?

Tags: python, time, interface, wxpython, python-imaging-library

My SwapImage function works perfectly in 5 areas of my script except for one part.

When the 'CompileImages' is called it starts processing images. I want to toggle an image in the line *before* that call to the function, but it seems to lock up the interface immediately and doesnt toggle it.

Is there a way to force it to run the toggle image function before it then moves on (and locks up)?

```
#the button I’m using…
genButton = wx.lib.buttons.GenButton(panel2, -1, label='Generate', pos=(8, 66), size=(136, 26))
genButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.RunCompileFunction)

#… calls this function
def RunCompileFunction(self, event):

        self.SwapImage(image_fileprogress)
        self.CompileImages(self)

#this SwapImage function works at every other point EXCEPT in the above function, it seems to skip over it as if it has more important things to do.
#Curiously if I comment out the call to CompileImages function it DOES swap the image.
def SwapImage(self, imagename):
    self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(panel1, -1, imagename, (0, 0))
    backgroundimage = imagename

#This function just starts processing images and causes the interface lockup
def CompileImages(self, event):

            if len(MyFrame.filenames) > 8 and len(MyFrame.maskfiles) <= 2:
        print("Ensure you've dropped your mask files too!")


    #myCursor = wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_WAIT)
    #frame.SetCursor(myCursor)

    global coloralphareq
    global opacityalphareq

    # get first image size and save to variable
    getsize = Image.open(MyFrame.filenames[0])
    mwidth, mheight = getsize.size

    # get its .extension format
    # imgformat = str(x)[-3:]
    # imgformat = (str(MyFrame.filenames[0].format))
    # print(imgformat)

    # for each image in the list...
    for map in maptypes:

        # print(map)

        # files = any file with the current mapname in it
        files = [s for s in MyFrame.filenames if map in s]
        # print(files)

        if len(files) > 0:

            map = map[:-1]

            # remove names that are clashing
            if map == "Normal": self.RemoveFiles(files, "Normal_OpenGL.")
            if map == "Normal_OpenGL": self.RemoveFiles(files, "Normal.")
            if map == "AO": self.RemoveFiles(files, "Mixed_AO.")
            if map == "Metallic": self.RemoveFiles(files, "MetallicSmoothness.")
            if map == "MetallicSmoothness": self.RemoveFiles(files, "Metallic.")

            if len(files) > 0:
                # find mode, format, size

                # choose the background alphaColor
                if map == "Base_Color" or map == "BaseColor" or map == "Diffuse":
                    if self.coloralphareq == 1:
                        self.CompileTheseImagesRGBA(map, files, (0, 0, 0, 0), 'RGBA', 0, (0, 0, 0, 0), mwidth,
                                                    mheight)
                    elif self.coloralphareq == 0:
                        self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (0, 0, 0))
                elif map == "Opacity":
                    if self.opacityalphareq == 1:
                        self.CompileTheseImagesRGBA(map, files, (0, 0, 0, 0), 'RGBA', 0, (0, 0, 0, 0), mwidth,
                                                    mheight)
                    elif self.opacityalphareq == 0:
                        self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (256, 256, 256))
                elif map == "Normal_OpenGL" or map == "Normal":
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (128, 128, 255))
                elif map == "AlbedoTransparency" or map == "MetallicSmoothness" or map == "SpecularSmoothness":
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (0, 0, 0, 0))
                elif map == "Height":
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (128, 128, 128))
                elif map == "Roughness":
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (136, 136, 136))
                elif map == "Mixed_AO" or map == "Reflection" or map == "AO":
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (256, 256, 256))
                elif map == "Glossiness" or map == "f0" or map == "ior":
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGB(map, files, (187, 187, 187))
                else:
                    self.CompileTheseImagesRGBA(map, files, (0, 0, 0, 0), 'RGBA', 0, (0, 0, 0, 0), mwidth, mheight)
```

Comment: Can you show `CompileTheseImagesRGB` as well?

Comment: Note that the line `backgroundimage = imagename` doesn't do anything (unless `backgroundimage` has global scope).

Comment: @101 I have edited to include the CompileImages function (which I accidentally also mislabelled as CompileTheseImagesRGB (here only, not in the original script). You're correct about backgroundimage - its for another purpose.

Comment: @101 to clarify - CompileImages is a function which then runs another function which in turn starts Opening and Pasting images into each other using PIL. The issue isn't with these functions at all other than that they lock up the interface while they do their work. Can I use a time delay to ensure the SwapImages line is 100% executed before the next line is?

Comment: I can see a couple of potential issues. You call `self.SwapImage(image_fileprogress)` but `image_fileprogress` doesn't seem to be defined. `SwapImage` is expecting the argument `imagename`. Check the argument you're actually passing is correct. You call `self.CompileImages(self)`, but the function expects argument `event`, not `self` (`self` is automatically passed to instance methods).